# Working with ExpressionEngine new method for tools_model::get_files()

Tags: php, expressionengine

I am trying to learn ExpressionEngine and working through [this sample module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html):

> *The best way to understand ExpressionEngine modules is to dissect one. Thus we present the ‘third party’ Download module. This module is fairly typical, and includes a backend control panel, its own database tables, adds a tab with fields to the publish page, and in general uses all of the standard files used in module creation.*

However, since EE now has removed the `get_files` method in EE 2.6 ([change log](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-6-0))

How do I get the list of files from a certain directory?

Comment: If you don't get the answer you are looking for here you can try posting on http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And if you're going to cross-post, make sure to [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667) before.

Comment: I posted in the expressionengine.stackoverflow.com. I am not sure if I need to delete this question from here.

Answer (score 1):

In the _map function held in mcp.Downloads.php around line 576

You can replace:

```
$files = $this->EE->tools_model->get_files($dir->server_path, $dir->allowed_types);
```

with

```
$this->EE->load->model('file_model');
$files = $this->EE->file_model->get_raw_files($dir->server_path, $dir->allowed_types);
```

That worked for me.